# How to authenticate using appid and appsecret in nodejs using https request

Tags: node.js, https

Here is the sample code for my application. Why It's not working ?

Error:

> `"{"error":"unauthorized","error_description":"An Authentication object was not found in the SecurityContext"}"`

```
var post_data = JSON.stringify({
'appid' : results.appid,
'appsecret': results.appsecret,
});

var url = serviceUrl+"/oauth-service/oauth/token?grant_type=client_credentials";
var post_options = {
            host: url,
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            },
            data:post_data
        };

const req = https.request(post_options, function(res) {
res.setEncoding('utf8');
res.on('data',function(chunk){
console.log(chunk);
});
});
req.write(post_data);
req.end();
```

Comment: Can you provide the api doc of the `oauth-service` you use?

Answer (score 0):

From the HTTPS request side, you don't need to have `data` in `post_options` (the data is sent using `write`).

More importantly, you need to set the `Content-Length` header to `Buffer.byteLength(post_data)`.

Also, the `host` (or `hostname`) field should contain just the hostname (e.g. `www.facebook.com` - no `https://` is needed) and the rest of the URL (e.g. `/oauth_service/...`) should be put in the `path` field.

Here's an example adapted from the [node.js docs](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_http_request_options_callback). They only provide examples for `http` but it's mostly the same as for `https`:

```
const postData = JSON.stringify({
  'msg': 'Hello World!'
});

const options = {
  hostname: 'www.google.com',
  path: '/upload',
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'Content-Length': Buffer.byteLength(postData)
  }
};

const req = https.request(options, (res) => {
  console.log(`STATUS: ${res.statusCode}`);
  console.log(`HEADERS: ${JSON.stringify(res.headers)}`);
  res.setEncoding('utf8');
  res.on('data', (chunk) => {
    console.log(`BODY: ${chunk}`);
  });
  res.on('end', () => {
    console.log('No more data in response.');
  });
});

req.write(postData);
req.end();
```

Note that without specifying which service you're working with, it's impossible to say whether you're implementing the protocol correctly (e.g. whether the URL is correct, whether your request body is correct, etc.). So if you fix the `Content-Length` and things still don't work, please provide more information.